# How to wait for itemCount in ListView in Future Builder flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I want to build cards on the basis of data received from the future which returns a map. Since `cardDetails` is being fetched from the backend, it requires some time but while building the cards using `ListView.builder`, it reaches to `itemCount` before the data is fetched which makes `cardDetails` to be `null`. If I hardcode the value of `itemCount` then, the error disappears and I get cards as required. Any clues on how to solve this issue would be helpful.

Update: It is going into the `snapshot.hasError` condition but I'm not able to figure out which error is it

In UI

```
 if (_localStorageService.getStringFromLocalStorage() != 'testFalse')
              FutureBuilder(
                future: _localStorageService.getMapFromLocalStorage(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    cardDetails = snapshot.data;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        print("Shared Pref hasData");
                        return cardDetails == null
                            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                            : HomepageCards(
                                user: widget.user,
                                cardDetails: cardDetails[
                                    cardDetails.keys.toList()[index]],
                              );
                      },
                      // verify if cardDetails is null to prevent app crash
                      itemCount:
                          (cardDetails == null ? 0 : cardDetails.keys.length),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      controller: _controller,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
//                    TODO: Shimmer skeleton
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              )
            else
              StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                stream: Firestore()
                    .collection('homepage')
                    .document(widget.user.uid)
                    .collection('h')
                    .document('28032020')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data != null) {
                    cardDetails = {};
                    snapshot.data.data.forEach((index, individualDetail) {
                      cardDetails[index] = individualDetail;
                    });
                    _localStorageService
                        .storeCardInSharedPreference(cardDetails);
                    cardDetailKeys = snapshot.data.data.keys;
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
//                    TODO: Show skeletal shimmer
                  } else {
                    // TODO: Convert it to Shimmer with card skeletal layout
                    CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                  return cardDetails == null
                      ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                      : ListView.builder(
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return HomepageCards(
                              user: widget.user,
                              cardDetails:
                                  cardDetails[cardDetails.keys.toList()[index]],
                            );
                          },
                          itemCount: (cardDetailKeys == null
                              ? 0
                              : cardDetailKeys.length),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          controller: _controller,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                        );
                },
              )
```

LocalStorage Service for Shared Preferences

```
class LocalStorageService {
  static SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;
  final String screenkey;
  String value;
  String _initialSharedValue;

  LocalStorageService({@required this.screenkey});

  initialiseLocalStorage() async {
    _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    persist(screenkey);
  }

  Future<void> persist(String key) async {
    _initialSharedValue = _sharedPreferences?.getString(key);
    // will be null if never previously saved
    if (_initialSharedValue == null) {
      _initialSharedValue = 'testFalse';
    }
    await _sharedPreferences?.setString(screenkey, _initialSharedValue);
    print("share = ${_sharedPreferences?.getString(screenkey)}");
  }

  storeCardInSharedPreference(Map cardDetails) async {
    await _sharedPreferences?.setString(screenkey, json.encode(cardDetails));
  }

  getMapFromLocalStorage() async {
    return await json.decode(_sharedPreferences?.getString(screenkey));
  }

  String getStringFromLocalStorage() {
    return _sharedPreferences?.getString(screenkey);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are saying that if you have a date, fill in the cardlist, otherwise display the ListView, so the ListView is trying to be displayed without data (which will give an error) and will only have data in the next setState because cardList will be filled (so it should work when you do the hotreload or go to another page).

Comment: What I am trying to say is that the data is there which is being fetched from the backend. If it is being fetched from firebase then it will go normally and write that data in shared preference. Now since the data is there in the shared preference, next time whenever I go online, I check if there is data in shared preference; I load it in `cardDetails` and pass it to the `ListView.builder` but, this takes some time during which `cardDetails` is null. I want to make it hold for some time in which the data is fetched from shared Preference and passed onto `cardDetails`

Comment: What happens if you put the return ListView.builder inside the snapshot.hasData like I did in the example?

Comment: Updated code. It shows only the circular progress indicator until I switch to a new tab and come back. Without `return CircularProgressIndicator();` it throws an error `build function returned null` and asked me to add a `Container` at least with 0 `width` and `height`

Answer (score 1):

This is because regardless of the status of your futurebuilder, Listview is being returned.
If you want to control the status of your futurebuilder, you must put the return inside your if/else/case.

Thus:

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: _localStorageService.getStringFromLocalStorage(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                cardDetails = snapshot.data;
                print("number of cards = ${cardDetails.keys.length}");
                return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  print("card details in futute : ${snapshot.data}");
                  return cardDetails == null
                      ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                      : HomepageCards(
                          user: widget.user,
                          cardDetails:
                              cardDetails[cardDetails.keys.toList()[index]],
                        );
                },
                // verify if cardDetails is null to prevent app crash
                itemCount: (cardDetails == null? 0: cardDetails.keys.length),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                controller: _controller,
                shrinkWrap: true,
              );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print("Error here in snapshot");
                return Center(child:Text("An error has occurred"));
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }

            },
          )
```

Comment: By this method, no cards display even when the value of `cardDetails` is fetched. I have to do a hot restart/switch to another screen to make it work.

Comment: Also, it is going in the `snapshot.hasError` condition but I am not able to figure out which error is it.

Comment: I saw your edited response, and you did it completely differently than I recommended here.

Comment: My bad. I updated my codebase but forgot to update it here. Updating it now to the latest one.